# Trying to Figure Out Strange Protocol Results in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, hierarchy

Here's the deal. I have run across this behavior in my implementation programming, and it has really puzzled me. I'm trying to figure out why it happens, so I can account for it in the future.

I'll paste a fairly involved (but minimal) playground in a minute, but I wanted to outline the issue, first.

The issue is that, if I define a class (not a struct) as conforming to a protocol with a default implementation, then override that by implementing the defined method, the protocol default implementation keeps getting executed, even when I'd expect the secondary implementation to be executed, and inheritance hierarchies get ignored.

Below, I have the playground (latest Xcode), and the resulting printout.

**WHAT I EXPECT**

Everything should follow the example set by the direct method call (1). This includes a couple of fallbacks to the protocol defaults.

**WHAT ACTUALLY HAPPENS**

The default implementation in the protocols (from which the classes derive/to which the classes conform) keeps getting executed.

The most puzzling ones are (6) - (8).

(2) - (4) are also a bit weird, as D and E (and Q and R) get printed correctly, but none of the other ones do.

Does anyone have any idea why I might be getting this behavior?

**THE HIERARCHY MAP**

[image: Pseudo-UML Diagram of the Hierarchy]

**THE PLAYGROUND:**

```
// MARK: - Test Functions

// Argument is Class A
func printValueFromClassA(_ inValueAsClassA: A) {
    inValueAsClassA.printValue()
}

// Argument is Class H
func printValueFromClassH(_ inValueAsClassH: H) {
    inValueAsClassH.printValue()
}

// Argument is Class J
func printValueFromClassJ(_ inValueAsClassJ: J) {
    inValueAsClassJ.printValue()
}

// Argument is Class D
func printValueFromClassD(_ inValueAsClassD: D) {
    inValueAsClassD.printValue()
}

// Argument is the Root protocol
func printValueFromProtocolA(_ inValueAsProtocolA: PA) {
    inValueAsProtocolA.printValue()
}

// Argument is the first derived protocol
func printValueFromProtocolB(_ inValueAsProtocolB: PB) {
    inValueAsProtocolB.printValue()
}

// Argument is the second derived protocol
func printValueFromProtocolC(_ inValueAsProtocolC: PC) {
    inValueAsProtocolC.printValue()
}

// MARK: - Protocols

// Root protocol: Defines the method
protocol PA {
    func printValue()
}

// Root protocol default implementation
extension PA {
    func printValue() { print("\t\tProtocol A") }
}

// Derived protocol: Depends on Root protocol default
protocol PB: PA { }

// Derived protocol: defines a new default implementation
protocol PC: PB { }

// Deived protocol default implementation
extension PC {
    func printValue() { print("\t\tProtocol C") }
}

// MARK: - Classes

// Direct conformance to PA; relying on the default implementation of the conforming method
class A: PA { }

// Derives from A, but implements the conforming method
class B: A {
    func printValue() { print("\t\tClass B") }
}

// Derives from B, and overrides the conforming method
class C: B {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass C") }
}

// Direct conformance to PB (which is based on PA), and implements the conforming method
class D: PB {
    func printValue() { print("\t\tClass D") }
}

// Derives from D, and overrides the conforming method
class E: D {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass E") }
}

// Direct conformance to PA, but defines the conforming method
class F: A {
    func printValue() { print("\t\tClass F") }
}

// Derives from C, and overrides the conforming method (second override)
class G: C {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass G") }
}

// Direct conformance to PB, but relies on the default implementation of the conforming method
class H: PB { }

// Derives from H, but implements the conforming method.
class I: H {
    func printValue() { print("\t\tClass I") }
}

// Direct conformance to the second derived protocol, and relies on that protocol's default implementation
class J: PC { }

// Derived from J, but implements the conforming method
class K: J {
    func printValue() { print("\t\tClass K") }
}

// Derived from J, and overrides the method
class L: K {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass L") }
}

// Derived from F, and overrides the method
class M: F {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass M") }
}

// Derived from I, and overrides the method
class N: I {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass N") }
}

// Derived from N, and overrides the method
class O: N {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass O") }
}

// Derived from L, and overrides the method
class P: L {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass P") }
}

// Direct conformance to the second derived protocol, but implements the conforming method
class Q: PC {
    func printValue() { print("\t\tClass Q") }
}

// Derived from Q, and overrides the method
class R: Q {
    override func printValue() { print("\t\tClass R") }
}

// MARK: - Testing

// MARK: instance definitions
let instanceOfA = A()
let instanceOfB = B()
let instanceOfC = C()
let instanceOfD = D()
let instanceOfE = E()
let instanceOfF = F()
let instanceOfG = G()
let instanceOfH = H()
let instanceOfI = I()
let instanceOfJ = J()
let instanceOfK = K()
let instanceOfL = L()
let instanceOfM = M()
let instanceOfN = N()
let instanceOfO = O()
let instanceOfP = P()
let instanceOfQ = Q()
let instanceOfR = R()


// MARK: Directly calling the instance methods
print("1) Direct Method Call:")
print("\tClass A:")
instanceOfA.printValue()                // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass B:")
instanceOfB.printValue()                // "Class B"
print("\tClass C:")
instanceOfC.printValue()                // "Class C"
print("\tClass D:")
instanceOfD.printValue()                // "Class D"
print("\tClass E:")
instanceOfE.printValue()                // "Class E"
print("\tClass F:")
instanceOfF.printValue()                // "Class F"
print("\tClass G:")
instanceOfG.printValue()                // "Class G"
print("\tClass H:")
instanceOfH.printValue()                // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass I:")
instanceOfI.printValue()                // "Class I"
print("\tClass J:")
instanceOfJ.printValue()                // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass K:")
instanceOfK.printValue()                // "Class K"
print("\tClass L:")
instanceOfL.printValue()                // "Class L"
print("\tClass M:")
instanceOfM.printValue()                // "Class M"
print("\tClass N:")
instanceOfN.printValue()                // "Class N"
print("\tClass O:")
instanceOfO.printValue()                // "Class O"
print("\tClass P:")
instanceOfP.printValue()                // "Class P"
print("\tClass Q:")
instanceOfQ.printValue()                // "Class Q"
print("\tClass R:")
instanceOfR.printValue()                // "Class R"

// MARK: Calling via a function that requires the argument be the Root protocol
print("\n2) printValueFromProtocolA(_: PA):")
print("\tClass A:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfA)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass B:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfB)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass C:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfC)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass D:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfD)    // "Class D"
print("\tClass E:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfE)    // "Class E"
print("\tClass F:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfF)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass G:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfG)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass H:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfH)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass I:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfI)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass J:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfJ)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass K:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfK)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass L:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfL)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass M:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfM)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass N:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfN)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass O:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfO)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass P:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfP)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass Q:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfQ)    // "Class Q"
print("\tClass R:")
printValueFromProtocolA(instanceOfR)    // "Class R"

// MARK: Calling via a function that requires the argument be the first Derived protocol
print("\n3) printValueFromProtocolB(_: PB):")
print("\tClass D:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfD)    // "Class D"
print("\tClass E:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfE)    // "Class E"
print("\tClass H:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfH)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass I:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfI)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass J:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfJ)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass K:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfK)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass L:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfL)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass N:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfN)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass O:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfO)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass P:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfP)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass Q:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfQ)    // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass R:")
printValueFromProtocolB(instanceOfR)    // "Protocol A"

// MARK: Calling via a function that requires the argument be the second Derived protocol
print("\n4) printValueFromProtocolC(_: PC):")
print("\tClass J:")
printValueFromProtocolC(instanceOfJ)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass K:")
printValueFromProtocolC(instanceOfK)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass L:")
printValueFromProtocolC(instanceOfL)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass P:")
printValueFromProtocolC(instanceOfP)    // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass Q:")
printValueFromProtocolC(instanceOfQ)    // "Class Q"
print("\tClass R:")
printValueFromProtocolC(instanceOfR)    // "Class R"

// MARK: Calling via a function that requires the argument be an instance or subclass of Class D
print("\n5) printValueFromClassD(_: D):")
print("\tClass D:")
printValueFromClassD(instanceOfD)       // "Class D"
print("\tClass E:")
printValueFromClassD(instanceOfE)       // "Class E"

// MARK: Calling via a function that requires the argument be an instance or subclass of Class A
print("\n6) printValueFromClassA(_: A):")
print("\tClass A:")
printValueFromClassA(instanceOfA)       // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass B:")
printValueFromClassA(instanceOfB)       // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass C:")
printValueFromClassA(instanceOfC)       // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass G:")
printValueFromClassA(instanceOfG)       // "Protocol A"

// MARK: Calling via a function that requires the argument be an instance or subclass of Class H
print("\n7) printValueFromClassH(_: H):")
print("\tClass H:")
printValueFromClassH(instanceOfH)       // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass I:")
printValueFromClassH(instanceOfI)       // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass N:")
printValueFromClassH(instanceOfN)       // "Protocol A"
print("\tClass O:")
printValueFromClassH(instanceOfO)       // "Protocol A"

// MARK: Calling via a function that requires the argument be an instance or subclass of Class J
print("\n8) printValueFromClassJ(_: J):")
print("\tClass J:")
printValueFromClassJ(instanceOfJ)       // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass K:")
printValueFromClassJ(instanceOfK)       // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass L:")
printValueFromClassJ(instanceOfL)       // "Protocol C"
print("\tClass P:")
printValueFromClassJ(instanceOfP)       // "Protocol C"
```

**THE PRINTOUT:**

```
1) Direct Method Call:
    Class A:
        Protocol A
    Class B:
        Class B
    Class C:
        Class C
    Class D:
        Class D
    Class E:
        Class E
    Class F:
        Class F
    Class G:
        Class G
    Class H:
        Protocol A
    Class I:
        Class I
    Class J:
        Protocol C
    Class K:
        Class K
    Class L:
        Class L
    Class M:
        Class M
    Class N:
        Class N
    Class O:
        Class O
    Class P:
        Class P
    Class Q:
        Class Q
    Class R:
        Class R

2) printValueFromProtocolA(_: PA):
    Class A:
        Protocol A
    Class B:
        Protocol A
    Class C:
        Protocol A
    Class D:
        Class D
    Class E:
        Class E
    Class F:
        Protocol A
    Class G:
        Protocol A
    Class H:
        Protocol A
    Class I:
        Protocol A
    Class J:
        Protocol C
    Class K:
        Protocol C
    Class L:
        Protocol C
    Class M:
        Protocol A
    Class N:
        Protocol A
    Class O:
        Protocol A
    Class P:
        Protocol C
    Class Q:
        Class Q
    Class R:
        Class R

3) printValueFromProtocolB(_: PB):
    Class D:
        Class D
    Class E:
        Class E
    Class H:
        Protocol A
    Class I:
        Protocol A
    Class J:
        Protocol C
    Class K:
        Protocol C
    Class L:
        Protocol C
    Class N:
        Protocol A
    Class O:
        Protocol A
    Class P:
        Protocol C
    Class Q:
        Class Q
    Class R:
        Class R

4) printValueFromProtocolC(_: PC):
    Class J:
        Protocol C
    Class K:
        Protocol C
    Class L:
        Protocol C
    Class P:
        Protocol C
    Class Q:
        Class Q
    Class R:
        Class R

5) printValueFromClassD(_: D):
    Class D:
        Class D
    Class E:
        Class E

6) printValueFromClassA(_: A):
    Class A:
        Protocol A
    Class B:
        Protocol A
    Class C:
        Protocol A
    Class G:
        Protocol A

7) printValueFromClassH(_: H):
    Class H:
        Protocol A
    Class I:
        Protocol A
    Class N:
        Protocol A
    Class O:
        Protocol A

8) printValueFromClassJ(_: J):
    Class J:
        Protocol C
    Class K:
        Protocol C
    Class L:
        Protocol C
    Class P:
        Protocol C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override a method that method needs to be implemented, so if you try to use the `override` keyword in B you get a compilation error since while A conforms to PA it doesn't implement the function in PA but uses the default one instead.

So this is most likely the reason for the confusion, since A hasn't implemented `printValue` it can't be overridden even though objects of type A can be called with it, `a.printValue()`, since it relies on the default implementation of the protocol.

Given this I think most of the test cases can be understood why they behave the way they do although I have only focused on case 6.

Implement `printValue()` in A and see what happens. You get compilation errors first that needs to be fixed but after that the output will be what you have expected.

Regarding the print out for case 6, since nothing is overriden from A all objects sent to `printValueFromClassA` will be treated as an instance of A and will be using the protocol default implementation.

Comment: You are correct in this. I don't think the vTable exists until the first definition of the method in a class (as opposed to a protocol default). The issue is that B implements it, and C and G override that; yet they all still print the protocol default.

Comment: Just a quick legend for my "pseudo-UML" diagram: Purple is protocol, yellow is class. Magenta is protocol default. Regular text is original definition, and italic is override.

Comment: I also redid the playground to emit printouts that might help to match the results to the map.

Comment: @ChrisMarshall I added a paragraph about case 6 to my answer

Comment: Also, I have encountered this while designing an SDK, and I wanted to allow the entities to be expressed as protocol-conformant, as opposed to class/struct-sublassed.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give you a greencheck, even if this doesn't cover all cases (lots of moving parts). I suspect that I'm really guilty of trying to leverage the language beyond its sensible bounds, and need to be a bit more plebeian.

Comment: OK. I’m pretty sure I figured it out. It basically makes sense, but I think this is long enough as it is. I’ll probably write up an article on my site about it. I know the _what_, but I’ll need to spend some quality time on https://godbolt.org to see if I can determine the _why_

Answer (score 0):

OK. I am leaving Joakim's greencheck, but I can now speak to this more conclusively.

It's a "sorta-kinda" bug in Swift.

Basically, if you override a method/property in a class hierarchy that is based on a protocol that has a default implementation, the vtable for the class hierarchy doesn't exist until you access the entity at a level in which it would exist without the default implementation.

I know that doesn't make sense, and I'm afraid that my explanation may be too long and involved for this venue, but I describe it in detail, [here](https://littlegreenviper.com/miscellany/swiftwater/the-curious-case-of-the-protocol-default/).

I do have a simpler (than above) gist that shows it, [here](https://gist.github.com/ChrisMarshallNY/99fd5459e5c02f21e38b4a4c858becb2).

I'll paste the playground from that gist, but it's kinda long:

```
// This is the little demo, at the start.
protocol A {
    var thisIsRequired: String { get }
    var thisIsOptional: String { get }
}

extension A {
    var thisIsOptional: String { get { "" } set {} }
}

struct conformsToA: A {
    var thisIsRequired: String { "Struct conformsToA" }
}

// In the first protocol, we don't use a default implementation (required conformance).
protocol PA {
    var myName: String { get }
}

struct SA: PA {
    var myName: String = "Struct A"
}

class CA: PA {
    var myName: String = "Class A"
}

class CB: CA {
    override var myName: String { get { "Class B" } set { } }
}

// In the second protocol, we add a default implementation (optional conformance).
protocol PB: PA { }

extension PB {
    var myName: String { "Protocol B" }
}

// This will "fall back" to the default implementation.
struct SB: PB { }

struct SC: PB {
    var myName: String = "Struct C"
}

// This will "fall back" to the default implementation.
class CC: PB { }

class CD: CC {
    var myName: String = "Class D"
}

class CE: CD {
    override var myName: String { get { "Class E" } set { } }
}

class CF: PB {
    var myName: String = "Class F"
}

class CG: CF {
    override var myName: String { get { "Class G" } set { } }
}

let structInstanceSA = SA()
let classInstanceCA = CA()
let classInstanceCB = CB()

// Part one is all about the required conformance protocol.
print("PART ONE")
print("\tDirect Print:")
print("\t\tStruct A: \(structInstanceSA.myName)")
print("\t\tClass A: \(classInstanceCA.myName)")
print("\t\tClass B: \(classInstanceCB.myName)")

func printAsProtoclA(_ inItem: PA) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsProtoclA(_: PA):")
print("\t\tStruct A: \(printAsProtoclA(structInstanceSA))")
print("\t\tClass A: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCA))")
print("\t\tClass B: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCB))")

func printAsStructA(_ inItem: SA) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsStructA(_: SA):")
print("\t\tStruct A: \(printAsStructA(structInstanceSA))")

func printAsClassA(_ inItem: CA) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsClassA(_: SA):")
print("\t\tClass A: \(printAsClassA(classInstanceCA))")
print("\t\tClass B: \(printAsClassA(classInstanceCB))")

let structInstanceSB = SB()
let structInstanceSC = SC()
let classInstanceCC = CC()
let classInstanceCD = CD()
let classInstanceCE = CE()
let classInstanceCF = CF()
let classInstanceCG = CG()

// Part two is where things get interesting.
print("PART TWO")
print("\tDirect Print:")
print("\t\tStruct B: \(structInstanceSB.myName)")
print("\t\tStruct C: \(structInstanceSC.myName)")
print("\t\tClass C: \(classInstanceCC.myName)")
print("\t\tClass D: \(classInstanceCD.myName)")
print("\t\tClass E: \(classInstanceCE.myName)")
print("\t\tClass F: \(classInstanceCF.myName)")
print("\t\tClass G: \(classInstanceCG.myName)")

func printAsProtoclB(_ inItem: PB) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsProtoclA(_: PA):")
print("\t\tStruct B: \(printAsProtoclA(structInstanceSB))")
print("\t\tStruct C: \(printAsProtoclA(structInstanceSC))")
print("\t\tClass C: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCC))")
print("\t\tClass D: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCD))")
print("\t\tClass E: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCE))")
print("\t\tClass F: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCF))")
print("\t\tClass G: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCG))")

print("\tprintAsProtoclB(_: PB):")
print("\t\tStruct B: \(printAsProtoclA(structInstanceSB))")
print("\t\tStruct C: \(printAsProtoclA(structInstanceSC))")
print("\t\tClass C: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCC))")
print("\t\tClass D: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCD))")
print("\t\tClass E: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCE))")
print("\t\tClass F: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCF))")
print("\t\tClass G: \(printAsProtoclA(classInstanceCG))")

func printAsStructB(_ inItem: SB) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsStructB(_: SB):")
print("\t\tStruct B: \(printAsStructB(structInstanceSB))")

func printAsStructC(_ inItem: SC) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsStructC(_: SC):")
print("\t\tStruct C: \(printAsStructC(structInstanceSC))")

func printAsClassC(_ inItem: CC) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsClassC(_: CC):")
print("\t\tClass C: \(printAsClassC(classInstanceCC))")
print("\t\tClass D: \(printAsClassC(classInstanceCD))")
print("\t\tClass E: \(printAsClassC(classInstanceCE))")

func printAsClassD(_ inItem: CD) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsClassD(_: CD):")
print("\t\tClass D: \(printAsClassD(classInstanceCD))")
print("\t\tClass E: \(printAsClassD(classInstanceCE))")

func printAsClassF(_ inItem: CF) -> String { inItem.myName }

print("\tprintAsClassF(_: SF):")
print("\t\tClass F: \(printAsClassF(classInstanceCF))")
print("\t\tClass G: \(printAsClassF(classInstanceCG))")

// In a perfect world, this would be a syntax error:
let name = classInstanceCC.myName
```

And here's the UML for the above:
[image: UML for the above playground]